# Populate backbone collection inside backbone sync

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I populate a backbone collection inside backbone-sync in a way that the resultant collection may be used outside the backbone sync.

Here is an example:

```
mycollection = new MyCollection();
mycollection.fetch();

// after a few seconds ... it triggers the success function

mycollection.length; //prints 0 :S
```

This is the code of my backbone sync:

```
define(["backbone"], function (bb) {
        bb.sync = function (method, model, options) {

            var sql = "";

            if (!model.tabla) {
                if (options && options.error)
                    options.error("No property 'tabla' for model");
            }

            switch (method) {
                case 'create':
                    break;
                case 'update':
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    break;
                case 'read':
                    sql = "select * from " + model.tabla;
                    break;
            }

            console.log("MODELO", model);

            if (app.db == undefined) return;

            app.db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(sql, [], function (tx, res) {
                        var resp = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                            resp.push(res.rows.item(i));
                        }

                        if (options && options.success) options.success(resp);
                    }
                );
            }, function (e) {
                console.log(e);

                if (options && options.error) options.error(e);
            });
        }
    }
);
```

My problem is that the input model doesn't get modified with the result array. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow exactly what you are trying to accomplish here. Am I correct that you are wanting to interact with the browsers local storage instead of an external server?  If that's the case, look into Backbone.localstorage extension http://documentup.com/jeromegn/backbone.localStorage

Comment: @JonathanW seems you do it in the right way. I've created jsfiddle with simple example of overwriting `Backbone.sync` method which modify external collection well. http://jsfiddle.net/gEBfV/ the main feature is to call `options.success(resp);`

Answer (score 0):

New data for collection will be available only after success callback because of asynchronous call in your case.

You can use

```
mycollection.fetch().then(function() {
    console.log(mycollection.length);
});
```

Or

```
mycollection.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log(mycollection.length);
    }
});
```

Or even

```
mycollection.on("fetch-complete", function() {
    console.log(mycollection.length);
});

mycollection.fetch({
    success: function(collection) {
        collection.trigger("fetch-complete");
    }
});
```